# How to make a type (or class) that maps a field to another?

Tags: class, dictionary, types, syntax, dart

How to have a `KeywordData` type or class that implements:

```
String keyword;
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> data;

var keywordData = {keyword: data};
```

except that `keywordData` has its own type?

I've tried:

```
class KeywordData {
  final String keyword;
  Map<String, Map<String, Object>> data;

  KeywordData({this.keyword, this.data});
    return {this.keyword: this.data};
}
```

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/65 which is currently being worked on https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/115

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the references. I was just wondering if it was possible to extend `MapEntry` (or `Map` ?) or something.

Comment: I don't think you can extend `MapEntry` or at least it wouldn't have an effect with the dart:core Map implementations. You can build your own Map class. See for example https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-collection/MapMixin-class.html